# Comparing SQL database with Django schema using sqldiff

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I am using sqldiff for comparing my django and SQL database and it seem to be giving 
`ALTER TABLE table_country MODIFY id integer AUTO_INCREMENT;` for all the models present in an app. Running the above command on the SQL database results in 0 modifications- because this is already the state of the table.

Why is sqldiff telling me to modify id for all the models? (this is an automatic 'id' primary key that django inserts)

sqldiff- https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqldiff.html